# Window decorations are permanently lost when windows are maximised

Tags: xubuntu, virtualbox, xfce, gui, window-decoration

I am using a clean install of Xubuntu, running as a Guest on windows 7 using virtualbox, and default options for XFCE as the window manager.

For some reason when I maximise any window (or open a application that has a maximised window), the window decorations (title bar, close, minimise and maximise) are permanently lost, even when the window is un-maximised. How do I prevent this from happening?

I have tried changing as many settings as I can find in the System and Display tabs in virtual box that don't give me non-optimal settings (e.g. 3D acceleration), changing the amount of RAM, VRAM, CPU, monitors, re-installing guest additions, updating xubuntu packages, and tweaking the settings in the Window Manager Tweaks. Nothing tried so far seems to fix the issue.

Comment: It can be a problem with virtualbox. Modify some of its settings (such as using fullscreen or not) and see what happens. Also the driver for the graphics card may be at fault. Install the proprietary one using XFCE Settings|Aditional drivers. Also in XFCE settings there is "Window manager tweaks" which you can try to modify and see what you get.

Comment: @Reza thanks for the suggestions. See the added paragraph in my question for the things I have now tried. The driver was already set to a proprietary guest addition module.

Comment: This doesn't normally happen. Did you try running a live USB to see if you get this problem outside of Virtual Box?

Comment: @RolandiXor I could try this but Xubuntu hasn't always had this issue for me either. I booted it up one day and the bug suddenly appeared. It may have been a setting I changed or an update that occurred that caused it. I guess the next thing to do is to try a fresh vbox image.

Comment: @kikumbob good idea. It would be best to verify that this problem is repeatable under the same circumstances to help narrow it down.

Would you like your 50 rep back btw?

Comment: @RolandiXor I don't mind, I just wanted to make this question more visible in case someone had come across and solved the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least 90% of the problem was solved when I found the setting "Hide frame of windows when maximised" in Window Manager Tweaks > Accessibility. I can't believe I missed this setting and I don't remember turning it on.

It still seems to be a virtual box related bug that, when this setting is used, it is impossible to re-show the window decoration. But at least its avoidable!